# What would be the steps for buiding email confirmation in django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a profile system but when users sign up, I would like them to get an email that has a link which would confirm their email and finish their registration process. How exactly would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it yourself (send an email with confirmation link that contains a key based on user's id) or use some modules like django-registration (https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).